# How can I determine which Google Chrome extension is requesting notification access?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

While pruning the number of sites that are allowed to send notifications to me, I discovered one allowed notification rule that surprised me:  `*://www.goko.com/*`:

[image: Screenshot of Notifications while searching for goko]

(This is found at chrome://settings/content/notifications )

How can I find out *which* of my Google Chrome Extensions is enforcing that I allow notifications from goko.com (without brute-force disabling/uninstalling them until I discover that the permission is gone)?

Comment: You can perform a file search for chrome.contentSettings.notifications or just disable extensions one by one.

Comment: Neither a file search nor disabling extensions one by one helped.  It turns out that an installed Chrome _App_ (see chrome://apps for the list) was the culprit here, not a Chrome _Extension_ normally found in chrome://extensions .